# Chrome memory usage over 2.5GB for a single page?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, memory

I had 3 pages open from the Skysports website and noticed my laptop was on a serious slowdown. When checking the Task Manager I noticed chrome was using almost 5GB in total and one page alone was using 2.5GB of memory. It starts off low around 300MB then escalates. The page in question is here:

http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11667/11240916/man-utd8217s-ander-herrera-denies-being-involved-in-match-fixing

Although other pages where also rising memory too well over 1.5GB as well. I'm running on Windows 10 and the latest build of chrome with no ad blockers or script blockers.

Doe's anyone know what is happening? This can't be normal

Comment: [analyze memory usage grow with WPRUI/WPA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/memory-footprint-optimization-exercise-2) and use **https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com** as symbol server to get the function name of chrome. now look if you see what function allocates most RAM

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any extensions installed? If so, then try disabling them all and enabling them one-by-one to find out what extension causes the memory rise.

If none, then this link may help you: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OUVmQm5eQl8